# How to access tailwind colors from javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css

I am using ApexCharts and would like to use my tailwind colors (red-500, etc) to style my chart. I can't use css classes (so can't use theme() in a post-css context).

I also can't reference the default config because I have extended it already.

I could import my new config's colors, however this does not seem like a good way to do it (besides, some css classes could be generated with utilities, and would not be accessible this way).
I have also theorized that I could add a hidden html element to my DOM, get the css property from it and then remove, but this also seems like a bad approach.

Answer (score 29):

Check the official docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script

You can use the built-in helper `resolveConfig` to get your config.

Answer (score 24):

```js
import colors from 'tailwindcss/colors'
const green = colors.green[600] // #16a34a
```

> *This will only work for default Tailwind colors*

Comment: This will not take into account any new extensions/overwrite modfications of colors tho.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Only default Tailwind colros :/

Answer (score 17):

EDIT: Quick and easy way to import colors, including your extended ones:

```
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig'
import tailwindConfig from 'path/to/your/tailwind.config.js'

const fullConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig)

console.log(fullConfig.theme.colors.myCustomColor[50])
```

source: https://www.javascriptguides.com/how-to-access-tailwind-css-colors-from-javascript/

---

@mrp's answer is great if you want to go the official route. However, I didn't want to go through the trouble of adding another babel plugin.

Instead, you can just reference their colors at https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/src/public/colors.js

Then create an export in constants file i.e.

```
export default {
  inherit: 'inherit',
  current: 'currentColor',
  transparent: 'transparent',
  black: '#000',
  white: '#fff',
  slate: {
    50: '#f8fafc',
    100: '#f1f5f9',
    200: '#e2e8f0',
    300: '#cbd5e1',
    400: '#94a3b8',
    500: '#64748b',
    600: '#475569',
    700: '#334155',
    800: '#1e293b',
    900: '#0f172a',
  },
  ...
}
```

and then you can just do e.g.

```
import COLORS from 'constants/colors'

<Icon color={COLORS.emerald[700]} />
```

Comment: Hey man. Your fisrt answer works perfectly but not in my case. This is because in my case I have a ```const color = require('tailwind/colors')``` at the first line of my tailwind.config.js, so when I import it in my component it says:
' Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined' 

Would you have any idea of how to solve that?

Answer (score 5):

## TypeScript Support

Although the other answers work, when using TypeScript type inferrence is needed.

In order to do so, follow these steps:

1. Rename your `tailwind.config.(js | cjs)` file to `tailwind.config.ts`
2. Configure your file so that it exports an Object that Satisfies Tailwind's configuration. (See more here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#using-esm-or-type-script).

   ```
   // tailwind.config.ts
   import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";
   export default {
       ... // Your Tailwind configuration goes here.
   } satisfies Config;
   ```

---

### Optional Steps:

In my case, I was using React so I created a custom hook in order to re-use the resolved configuration.

If you're not using React, you can just adapt this to your Framework using a a normal function.

```
// React
import { useMemo } from "react";

// Third Party
import resolveConfig from "tailwindcss/resolveConfig";

// Project
import tailwindConfig from "../../tailwind.config.js";

export default function useTailwind() {
  const tailwind = useMemo(() => resolveConfig(tailwindConfig), [tailwindConfig]);
    
  return tailwind;
}
```

Comment: Underrated answer, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The config is just a js/ts file. So if all you need is the colors, a simple approach is to write that as a `const` and then export it separately. Example:

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss';

export const colors = {
  'custom-color-one': '#FFA210',
  'custom-color-two': '#3FCC48',
} as const; // "as const" makes it readonly and improves intellisense

const config: Config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors
      // ...the rest of your config
    },
  },
};

export default config;
```

In your target file, you can then:

```
import { colors } from '../../tailwind.config';

<MyComponent color={colors['custom-color-one']} />
```