# Tailwind - Get all possible background color class names in JS

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I have a Javascript App which is a playground for some UI Components made with **TailwindCSS**. These components are *customizable* (colors, background, etc).

For example, the user will be able to select a background color class from a dropdown (tailwind syntax - eg: `bg-indigo-400`) and the selected class will be applied to the displayed UI component.
(All the classes are already generated in CSS by using `safelist` option pattern in `tailwind.config`).

**The requirement:**

To populate the select dropdown options, I need to generate an array of all the possible background color classes, as strings, based on current Tailwind Configuration Colors:

For example, if my Tailwind Config contains has:

```js
theme: {
 colors: {
   brown: {
     50: '#fdf8f6',
     100: '#f2e8e5',
     ...
     900: '#43302b',
    },
   primary: '#5c6ac4',
 }
},
```

the available background color classes will be:
`bg-brown-50`, `bg-brown-100`.... `bg-brown-900`, `bg-primary`.

**What I've tried**

Based on this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70317546/1135971, I was to able to get the available colors:

```js
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig'
import tailwindConfig from 'path/to/your/tailwind.config.js'

const fullConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig)

console.log(fullConfig.theme.colors)
```

which gives me an object with the following format:

```js
{
    "brown": {
        "50": "#fdf8f6",
        "100": "#f2e8e5",
        ....
        "900": "#43302b"
    },
    "primary": "#5c6ac4"
}
```

Now, based on this object, I'll need to generate all the background color classes, perhaps looping through all the properties of the object (`Object.entries`) and generating the array of background color classes.

Is there any other approach? Maybe an exposed Tailwind function that I can import?

Comment: Just to make sure I understood your question correctly, you want an array of all the possible `bg-{colour}-{number}` classes as strings? Can I ask what it'd be used for? (I ask because this sounds a bit like it could be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))

Comment: Yes, I would need an array of classes, as strings.

Comment: In a project I have some UI Components based on Tailwind - eg buttons etc. I've build a playground (a form with some inputs) where a user can customize the button text and button background. The background is a Css class based on TailwindCss `bg-{colour}-{number}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your theme object through the `util/flattenColorPalette.js` function, which will give you an object with all the possible colour suffixes as keys and theme colours as values:

```js
import resolveConfig from "tailwindcss/resolveConfig"
import tailwindConfig from "path/to/your/tailwind.config.js"
import flatten from "tailwindcss/src/util/flattenColorPalette";

const fullConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig)

const theme = fullConfig.theme.colors;
const flatPalette = flatten(theme);

const classes = Object.keys(flatPalette);

/*
 * classes = [
 *   'inherit',     'current',     'transparent', 'black',       'white',
 *   'slate-50',    'slate-100',   'slate-200',   'slate-300',   'slate-400',
 *   …
 * ]
 */
```

You can use either regexes (more formally correct) or `String.prototype.endsWith` (probably easier to read for most) to filter the "inherit", "current" etc values out, and then do

```js
classes.map(suffix => `bg-${suffix}`);
```